# List user defined views from database

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, database-metadata

Is there a way to list user defined views alone. In MSSQL, when I tried to list tables and views using getTables() function of DatabaseMetadata of jdbc, it is showing all the views. But I don't need system views into my result set.

```
DatabaseMetadata dmd = connection.getMetaData();
tablesResultSet= dmd.getTables(dbName, null, null, new String[] { "TABLE", "VIEW" });
```

This is the code, I'm using to extract metadata. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might ask the database directly with a `SELECT` call and analyse the result:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type]='V' AND is_ms_shipped=0
```

`[type]='V'` will filter for `VIEW`s and `is_ms_shipped=0` will filter for objects which are created by users (were not installed from MS)

[Find details here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49940/is_ms_shipped-property-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @abubakkar - `SELECT TABLE_NAME AS VIEW_NAME FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEWS]` might be somewhat more portable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the schema into consideration. The default schema on MS SQL is dbo. So your call to the metadata should be:

```
DatabaseMetadata dmd = connection.getMetaData();
tablesResultSet= dmd.getTables(dbName, "dbo", null, new String[]   { "VIEW" });
```

Or you get all Schemas before by

```
dmd.getSchemas(dbName,"%");
```

And then loop all your 'working' schemas.

Comment: yes, except, that the default schema might have a different name.

Comment: In MySQL schema is not common, because its contained in the Database. So you use just the '%' as the schema name in MySQL.